# BACnet server as a docker application

Tags: python, docker, bacnet, bacpypes

On the Python BACnet stack bacpypes there is simple examples on how to make a BACnet server, like this [mini_device.py](https://github.com/JoelBender/bacpypes/blob/master/samples/mini_device.py) on the git repo.

The BACpypes applications require a `.ini` file like a config file which looks like that states the `address` of the NIC card you want to use:

```
[BACpypes]
objectName: OpenDsm
address: 192.168.0.109/24 
objectIdentifier: 500001
maxApduLengthAccepted: 1024
segmentationSupported: segmentedBoth
vendorIdentifier: 15
```

Trying to turn this into a docker container if I put this `mini_device.py` in a dir with the `BACpypes.ini`, `requirements.txt` for bacypes, and a `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image with Python 3.10
FROM python:3.10-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port 47808 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 47808/udp

# Define environment variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Run your Python script when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

A run in terminal `$ docker build -t bacnet-server-test .`

It builds just fine but when running it with `$ docker run -p 47808:47808/udp bacnet-server-test` I get an `OSError: [Errno 99] Address not available` error I think because the `BACpypes.ini` file is stating an incorrect `address` to use.

Would anyone have any advice to research on this? Am sort of a newbie in Docker thanks for any tips. Ideally if its possible it would be nice for the Python script to just bind the `address` to like an `eth0` adapter or something in Linux...?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/app.py", line 136, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/app.py", line 96, in main
    test_application = SampleApplication(this_device, args.ini.address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes/app.py", line 535, in __init__
    self.mux = UDPMultiplexer(self.localAddress)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes/bvllservice.py", line 96, in __init__
    self.directPort = UDPDirector(self.addrTuple)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bacpypes/udp.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.bind(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncore.py", line 333, in bind
    return self.socket.bind(addr)
OSError: [Errno 99] Address not available
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is working...add in these packages:

```
import subprocess
import configparser
```

And add in these functions `update_ini_address` and `get_ip_address` and modifications to the `main` as shown below with keeping the rest of `mini_device.py` the same:

```
def get_ip_address():
    try:
        # This will return the IP address of the default route interface (which should be the host's primary IP)
        output = subprocess.check_output(["ip", "route", "get", "1"]).decode("utf-8")
        for line in output.split("\n"):
            if "src" in line:
                return line.strip().split("src")[1].split()[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None


def update_ini_address(ini_file_path, new_address):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(ini_file_path)
    if "BACpypes" in config:
        config["BACpypes"]["address"] = new_address
        with open(ini_file_path, "w") as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)


def main():
    global test_av, test_bv, test_application

    detected_ip_address = get_ip_address()
    if detected_ip_address:
        print(f"Detected IP Address: {detected_ip_address}")
        # Update the ini file
        update_ini_address("BACpypes.ini", f"{detected_ip_address}/24")
    else:
        print("Unable to find IP address. Using the one from ini file.")

    # make a parser
    parser = ConfigArgumentParser(description=__doc__)

    # parse the command line arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if _debug:
        _log.debug("initialization")
    if _debug:
        _log.debug("    - args: %r", args)

    # make a device object
    this_device = LocalDeviceObject(ini=args.ini)
    if _debug:
        _log.debug("    - this_device: %r", this_device)

    # make a sample application
    test_application = SampleApplication(this_device, args.ini.address)

    # make an analog value object
    test_av = AnalogValueObject(
        objectIdentifier=("analogValue", 1),
        objectName="av",
        presentValue=0.0,
        statusFlags=[0, 0, 0, 0],
        covIncrement=1.0,
    )
    _log.debug("    - test_av: %r", test_av)

    # add it to the device
    test_application.add_object(test_av)
    _log.debug("    - object list: %r", this_device.objectList)

    # make a binary value object
    test_bv = BinaryValueObject(
        objectIdentifier=("binaryValue", 1),
        objectName="bv",
        presentValue="inactive",
        statusFlags=[0, 0, 0, 0],
    )
    _log.debug("    - test_bv: %r", test_bv)

    # add it to the device
    test_application.add_object(test_bv)

    # binary value task
    do_something_task = DoSomething(INTERVAL)
    do_something_task.install_task()

    _log.debug("running")

    run()

    _log.debug("fini")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `Dockerfile` no changes are needed. This is working for me on running this on a Rasp Pi

```
$ sudo docker build -t bacnet-server-test .
$ sudo docker run --network="host" bacnet-server-test
```

And the Docker container running `mini_device.py` finds the host OS IP address where it appears to work fine. From a separate Windows computer on my LAN test bench the `mini_device.py` BACnet is responding to the BACnet `who-is` from a BACnet scan tool...and the points of `mini_device.py` works as expected...